# What pandas function does change the column type in an "inline" manner?

Tags: python, pandas

I know that the following commands could help change the column type:

```
df['date'] = str(df['date']) 

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])

df['A'] = df.A.astype(np.datetime64)
```

But do you know a better way to change the column type in an inline manner to make it in one line following with other aggregating commands such as groupby, dropna, etc. For example:

```
df\
#.function to cast df.A to np.datetime64 \ 
.groupby('C') \
.apply(lambda x: x.set_index('A').resample('1M').sum())
```

Comment: The first example may not belong there as it doesn't change the dtype.

Comment: Also you might want to check [pd.Grouper](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to avoid temporarily setting the index and using resample.

Comment: Bear with me with the first example. You are right, the later example has something wrong to do with the resample because it creates new index and I'm trying to remove it inow..

Comment: I am so amazed by that you find the risk here so quick.. I did change the method to pd.Grouper and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [assign](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df.assign(A=pd.to_datetime(df['A']))
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['20150101', '20140702'], 'B': [1, 2]})
df
Out: 
          A  B
0  20150101  1
1  20140702  2

df.assign(A=pd.to_datetime(df['A']))
Out: 
           A  B
0 2015-01-01  1
1 2014-07-02  2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks Ayhan!